# Pagespeed still works on a new server even though it shouldnt

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php

I had mod_pagespeed installed on my previous server. I didn't use it and disallowed via .htaccess because after some testing it turned out that it actually slowed down my site. So it remained "disallowed" via .htaccess for a long time.

Today I moved to a new server and migrated user accounts using cPanel VHM migration feature. Supposedly it migrates only accounts and not configuration, but I have many problems now and I suspect this is primarily due to pagespeed. It's not installed on the new server because I dont need it, but somehow various logs and console messages show that pagespeed versions of files are still requested from time to time like the following "d14dafe2dc85d5ff8142236c3f55e0d4.pagespeed.jm.ReWsy_33cT.js" which causes random 404 errors and even 500 internal server errors.

How can it request pagespeed versions if pagespeed isnt installed? how is it possible? can anyone explain, please.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, fixed it. It was DNS problem.. data was being loaded from both servers. That is, had to wait for DNS propagation to finish.

Regarding "out of memory errors", the php limit was set to 32mb which is really low, so increasing that figure got rid of various errors.

Answer (score 0):

Likely search engines or spiders having these files still in their list and crawling your site.

Answer (score 0):

It rather suggests that your configuration on both webservers was far from optimal. Either you've not got a clean caching hierarchy defined (e.g. HTML pages are being cached for longer than javascript files) or these arise from conditional requests (which are mostly very bad for performance and should be stripped out on your server).

> because after some testing it turned out that it actually slowed down my site

Most likely because yo're not running a caching reverse proxy in front of the webserver, and/or you've not tuned the installation properly.

> and even 500 internal server errors

These shouldn't cause 500 errors - more likely there's something else broken in your installation / config.